# If I roll 2 dice, what is the probability that the sum is $7$ given that one die is a $1$?

Tags: probability

> If I roll 2 dice, what is the probability that the sum is $7$ given that one die is a $1$?

I got $2/36$? Any thoughts, thanks.

$(6,1)$ and $(1,6)$

Comment: What are **your** thoughts (i.e., how did you get that answer)?

Comment: 36 cannot be the denominator, because you know that one die is a 1.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

- There are $11$ scenarios in which one of the dice shows "1"
- Out of those, there are $2$ scenarios in which the sum of the dice is "7"

Comment: is it 2/11 ? still (6,1) (1,6)

Comment: @user108698: I don't understand your question.

Comment: the answer is 2/11 correct?

Comment: @user108698: Do you understand the hint?

Comment: Yeah looking at my sample space that makes sense

Comment: so I'm not going crazy it's 2/11